# Is it possible for Contao to not redirect to home page alias?

Tags: contao

Older Contao versions by default did not redirect to the first public page, so the front page was displayed with both `domain.com` and `domain.com/front-page.html` and neither was redirected to the other. However the newest Contao at least (4.8) does force a redirect from `domain.com` to `domain.com/front-page`.

There is one setting, **Do not redirect empty URLs**, which looks like it *could* do the trick, but, in my case at least, does not seem to do anything.

So how do I prevent Contao from redirecting from a "blank url" to the first published page of a website root? I'd much rather redirect the other way around, from `/front-page` to `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `alias` of your start page to `index`. The generated URL by Contao for the page with the alias `index` will always be without a path.

See also [the documentation about page aliases](https://docs.contao.org/manual/de/seitenstruktur/seiten-konfigurieren/#seitenaliase) (English version still WIP).